# How do I remove a new row, that added by pressing CTRL + I but it not committed yet, in SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQLDeveloper, I have added a row in a table by pressing CTRL + I but I have not committed it, now I want to remove it. When I select that row and press CTRL D, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turns *red* when I press CTRL+D.

However, as you didn't commit yet, just press F12 which performs **rollback** and that newly inserted row will disappear.

Comment: Well, I have made more rows that I want to keep them, there is only one row that I want to remove it. I don't think so rollback is helpful in this case.

Comment: Then commit all and remove one.

Answer (score 0):

I 'fat finger' 5 or 6 times, and accidentally 'create new rows' in my TABLE.

[image]

I haven't actually...I just have some 'local,' to my machine changes to the table, that I could 'COMMIT.'

But I don't want to COMMIT, I want to...UNDO those mistakes.

So I could...select the rows and hit the DELETE button, but that's extra work, not required.

If you have made NO OTHER CHANGES to your table, you could simply hit the ROLLBACK button.

[image]

See the log below 'Local changes cleared' - but once I hit 'Rollback' ANY uncommitted transactions or transactions not posted to the database, will be undone.